# Validating DataAnnotations with Validator class

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-4.0, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate a class decorated with data annotation with the [Validator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator(VS.100).aspx).

It works fine when the attributes are applied to the same class. But when I try to use a metadata class it doesn't work. Is there anything I should do with the Validator so it uses the metadata class? Here's some code..

this works:

```
public class Persona
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="La edad no puede ser negativa")]
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

this doesnt work:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Persona_Validation))]
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}

public class Persona_Validation
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "La edad no puede ser negativa")]
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

this is how I validate the instances:

```
ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(p, null, null);
List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(p, context, results, true);
```

thanks.

Comment: I cannot find ValidationContext within System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (MVC 2.0)
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Myster check that System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll is referenced in the project.

Comment: Simply use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/JimmyBoh/b7c135820c18a06648a5) (an extension method) and you can call p.Validate()

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/149264/377212.aspx

MVC recognizes the MetaDataType attribute, but other projects do not.  Before validating, you need to manually register the metadata class:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
            new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(Persona), typeof(Persona_Validation)), typeof(Persona));

ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(p, null, null);
List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(p, context, results, true);
```

Comment: I expanded on my answer to similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755340/validate-data-using-dataannotations-with-wpf-entity-framework/2467387#2467387

Comment: The `validateAllProperties` flag tripped me up. Its worth remembering to set that where appropriate!

Comment: @JeremyGruenwald , **ValidationContext** is not working for collections. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder, I haven't done this hands-on in years now, sorry. Are you trying to validate each object in a collection, or the collection itself as a property of a parent object (e.g. collection cannot be empty)? For the former, I would hope it would work to apply the same logic to the objects contained in the collection. For the latter, I think you'd probably have to write your own business logic.

Answer (score -1):

Try to move the metadata class into the same namespace as the Persona class if it isn't already.  I was having similar problems and moving my metadata class into the same namespace as the L2S model class worked for me.

Comment: It didnt work, I've also tried putting the metadata class inside the class, but no luck.