# how to use validation in EF in win application

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework-4

Hi
How can i use EF4 validation with windows application ?
I tried to add :
[Required()]
to entities but I couldn't because I don't know from any class can i get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at this:
[EF 4 Validation Using Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755340/validate-data-using-dataannotations-with-wpf-entity-framework)