# using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in console application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

Can I use "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;" for console application? or it is only for ASP.Net and MVC model.

Comment: Yes you can, Please refere the following reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854759/how-to-use-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-in-wpf-or-winforms-application

Comment: Yes. you can. There is not limitation. This is not apart of any mvc.net related NUget.