# How to Validate with data anotation in c#?

Tags: c#, validation, oop, console-application, data-annotations

I have simple program that validate with data anotatoin but when i use MetadataType for seperate data anotation , resualt validation always is true. Why result below code is always true ?

```
public partial class User
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}


[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
}

public class UserMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var u = new User
        {
            // must raise error
            FullName = "A"
        };

        var context = new ValidationContext(u, null, null);
        var list = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var isCorrect = Validator.TryValidateObject(u, context, list, true);

        // isCorrect always is True 
        Console.WriteLine(isCorrect);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a MVC project the the `MetaDataType` attribute gets recognized. Other projects will need a little help. Before you start validating, you will need to register the metadata class.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(User), typeof(UserMetadata)), typeof(User));
```

That should enable you to test your validation correctly.

There's a lot more information on this in a related topic answer from Jeremy Gruenwald -> [Validate data using DataAnnotations with WPF & Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755340/validate-data-using-dataannotations-with-wpf-entity-framework/2467387#2467387)